# Drag an element outside its scrollable parent div - ( React-Draggable )

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

**React-Draggable**, I am implementing a drag-drop functionality 
in which a **div** ( with an image and some elements ) has to be dragged and dropped into different categories, but 
when we drag the element its able to be dragged only within the parent div and
when we try to drag it out, div goes behind the div.

[image]

**Draggable element:**

```
<Draggable
        position={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        onDrag={this.props.groupPageDragStartHandler}
        onStop={(event) => this.props.groupPageDragStopHandler(event, this.props.group, this.props.pageInfo)}
        defaultClassNameDragging="groupItemDragging"
        >
        <div className="group-report-items col-sm-4">
            <div className="canvas-outer">
                <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" id={checkBoxId} value={checkBoxId} checked={this.state.selected} />
            <canvas
                    className="groupCanvas"
                    id={canvasId}
                    height="792"
                    width="612"
                    ref="imageCanvas"
                    onClick={(event) => this.selectHandler(event, this.props.group, this.props.pageInfo)}></canvas>
            <a canvas-id={canvasId} href="javascript:void(0)" className="search">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
                </i>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="trash">
                    <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onClick={(event) => this.props.onPageDeleteHandler(event, this.props.group, this.props.pageInfo)}>
                </i>
            </a>
        </div></div></Draggable>
```

Is there a way in which we could drag the element outside the parent div into its desired destination, I am using **React with Typescript**

**Note:** I am able to still drop the element into its destination, but the only thing is the div goes behind and it looks kind of bad.

Comment: "Note: I am able to still drop the element into its destination, but the only thing is the div goes behind and it looks kind of bad." - Is this not just a z-index css issue then? As opposed to a React-Draggable issue? Might be worth setting the z-index of <Draggable /> to something like 1000 and seeing where that gets you.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I did try it, setting z-index doesn't work.it doesn't come out when dragging, it still moves within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was, the div containing the drag elements had a scroll

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

when dragging I had the remove it.after which I was able to move the element outside the div. spent a lot of time trying to get the element out didn't think about tweaking the scroll.